why are my two docker containers not connecting to each other?
I have two docker containers, one running Kafka and one running python with the Kafka client. I am attempting to set the container with the python client as a consumer for the container running Kafka. both containers are on the same network. but then i am running my code to connect to the container i get the same error code:
your %3|1725885842.079|FAIL|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:localhost:172/bootstrap]: localhost:172/bootstrap: Connect to ipv4#127.0.0.1:172 failed: Connection refused (after 0ms in state CONNECT)text
below i will attach my docker network code and my python code:
docker inspect my-network
[
    {
        "Name": "my-network",
        "Id": "c920653a8c4d9e068887bce98dab2f5bf2f554e112a2cbd337d3a7feefc45b5b",
        "Created": "2024-09-06T14:39:28.375456878Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "02bf3754f2b27276db07762cf6237872dfa36bcd85d4e1feb7d7d6f13ff97a82": {
                "Name": "broker",
                "EndpointID": "13d97b89c9c4980c7c71b25e8aba4fc94d9a60b344720fca44fb66adc40af15b",        
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8fb0fab1c6c8f97033739a5936661e04df02de25c6a77cc9bb4c8259b21095a7": {
                "Name": "agitated_shirley",
                "EndpointID": "9c14de0df28233489e56b5354bd7621239eca948b5c4c7adabf3fccf6a98779d",        
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from confluent_kafka import Consumer

conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:172.20.0.3', 'group.id':'main-group','auto.offset.reset':'smallest'}

consumer = Consumer(conf)


running = True


i have tried creating new networks and containers from scratch. what am i doing wrong?

You messed up the 'bootstrap.servers' setting. Should be '172.20.0.3:<port>'

It looks like your container is connecting to itself (localhost) and not the Kafka broker container.  How are you starting the two containers?  (Consider deleting the docker network inspect output and replacing it with your docker-compose.yml file or docker network create and docker run commands.)  Where does the magic IP address 172.20.0.3 come from?  (You should be able to use the container name or Compose service name as a DNS name, and never need to manually look up the IP address.)

bootstrap.servers likely expects the address in the format host:[port]. Your error message tells you that it tries to connect to 127.0.0.1:172 (or localhost:172).
Change it to {'bootstrap.servers': '172.20.0.3'} or use the DNS name in the network {'bootstrap.servers': 'broker'}.

The localhost refers to the container itself, if you are running in same network.
So change the localhost to container name
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'broker:9092', 'group.id':'main-group', 'auto.offset.reset':'smallest'}

Change the kafka listening properties from server.properties file
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://broker:9092


The server.properties file would be modified by an environment variable on a container

First settings in your config
'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:172.20.0.3',

should look like host:port, something like
'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'

(replace 9092 with your kafka port if you have another)

Localhost will make the Python app connect to itself
